# Error while indexing to Elasticsearch with spark streaming, scala case class with more than 22 argument

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-streaming

I am using **Spark Streaming with Scala** to write the log data to **Elastic search**.

I am not able to **create case scala with more than 22 argument** required in my case and is not supported in scala 2.10.
So using the below approach to create the class instead of case class

Scala class

```
class FactUsage(d_EVENT_TYPE_NR: Long,EVENT_GRP_DESC: String,EVENT_DESC: String,CUST_TYPE_CD: Long,TICKET_RATING_CD: Long,BUS_UNIT_DESC: String,CUST_MKT_SEGM_DESC: String,EVENT_DTTM: String,EVENT_DTNR: Long,SERVED_PARTY_IMEI_NUM: String,SERVED_PARTY_IMSI_NUM: String,SERVED_PARTY_PHONE_NUM: Long,OTHER_PARTY_ID: String,EVENT_DURATION_QTY: Long,EVENT_VOLUME_DOWN_QTY: Long,EVENT_VOLUME_TOTAL_QTY: Long,EVENT_VOLUME_UP_QTY: Long,ACCESS_POINT_ID: String,d_CELL_NR: Long,d_CONTRACT_NR: Long,d_CUSTOMER_NR: Long,d_CUSTOMER_TOP_PARENT_NR: String,d_DEVICE_NR: Long,d_ORIGIN_DESTINATION_NR: Long,d_DIRECTION_NR: Long,d_OTHER_OPER_NR: Long,d_OTHER_SUBSCR_OPER_NR: Long,d_ROAMING_NR: Long,d_SALES_AGENT_NR: String,d_SERVED_OPER_NR: Long,d_SERVED_SUBSCR_OPER_NR: Long,d_TARIFF_MODEL_NR: Long,d_TERMINATION_NR: Long,d_USAGE_SERVICE_NR: Long,RUN_ID: String) extends Product with Serializable 
{
def canEqual(that:Any)=that.isInstanceOf[FactUsage]
def productArity = 35 // Number of columns

def productElement(idx: Int) = idx match 
{
case 0 => d_EVENT_TYPE_NR;case 1 =>EVENT_GRP_DESC;case 2 =>EVENT_DESC;case 3 =>CUST_TYPE_CD;case 4 =>TICKET_RATING_CD;case 5 =>BUS_UNIT_DESC;case 6 =>CUST_MKT_SEGM_DESC;case 7 =>EVENT_DTTM;case 8 =>EVENT_DTNR;case 9 =>SERVED_PARTY_IMEI_NUM;case 10 =>SERVED_PARTY_IMSI_NUM;case 11 =>SERVED_PARTY_PHONE_NUM;case 12 =>OTHER_PARTY_ID;case 13 =>EVENT_DURATION_QTY;case 14 =>EVENT_VOLUME_DOWN_QTY;case 15 =>EVENT_VOLUME_TOTAL_QTY;case 16 =>EVENT_VOLUME_UP_QTY;case 17 =>ACCESS_POINT_ID;case 18 =>d_CELL_NR;case 19 =>d_CONTRACT_NR;case 20 =>d_CUSTOMER_NR;case 21 =>d_CUSTOMER_TOP_PARENT_NR;case 22 =>d_DEVICE_NR;case 23 =>d_ORIGIN_DESTINATION_NR;case 24 =>d_DIRECTION_NR;case 25 =>d_OTHER_OPER_NR;case 26 =>d_OTHER_SUBSCR_OPER_NR;case 27 =>d_ROAMING_NR;case 28 =>d_SALES_AGENT_NR;case 29 =>d_SERVED_OPER_NR;case 30 =>d_SERVED_SUBSCR_OPER_NR;case 31 =>d_TARIFF_MODEL_NR;case 32 =>d_TERMINATION_NR;case 33 =>d_USAGE_SERVICE_NR;case 34 =>RUN_ID 
}
}
```

Spark Streaming Code to Write to Elasticsearch

```
val rddAbcServerLog = lines.filter(x => x.toString.contains("abc_server_logs"))
EsSparkStreaming.saveToEs(rddAbcServerLog.map(line => parser.formatDelimeted(line)).map(p => parser.runES(p.toString)), esindex + "/" + estype)
```

I have debugged and there is no issues with the functions used in lambda expression.
Error comes while writing to Elasticsearch

Error

```
17/04/15 11:34:05 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: Found unrecoverable error [xx.xxx.xx.xx:10200] returned Bad Request(400) - failed to parse; Bailing out..
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.processBulkResponse(RestClient.java:250)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.bulk(RestClient.java:202)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.tryFlush(RestRepository.java:220)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.flush(RestRepository.java:242)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.doWriteToIndex(RestRepository.java:182)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.writeToIndex(RestRepository.java:159)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:67)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$doSaveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:102)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$doSaveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
17/04/15 11:34:05 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: Found unrecoverable error [xx.xxx.xx.xx:10200] returned Bad Request(400) - failed to parse; Bailing out..
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.processBulkResponse(RestClient.java:250)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.bulk(RestClient.java:202)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.tryFlush(RestRepository.java:220)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.flush(RestRepository.java:242)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.doWriteToIndex(RestRepository.java:182)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.writeToIndex(RestRepository.java:159)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:67)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$doSaveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:102)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$doSaveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

17/04/15 11:34:05 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
17/04/15 11:34:05 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
17/04/15 11:34:05 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
```

Note: Code might have weird naming conventions and masked IPs, I have modified the code for posting to the public forum

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is cumbersome and error-prone. Instead, use multiple case classes.

```
case class Group(grpDesc: String, eventDesc: String)
case class Event(dttm: String, dtnr: String)
```

...and so on

Then when you've grouped all related items into their own case classes:

```
case class FactUsage(group: Group, event: Event, ...)
```

You should pass an instance of `FactUsage` to `saveToEs`.

Comment: Thanks Vidya for your answer!!! But the problem with this approach is: I have one index with 35 fields because of creating multiple case class my Elasticsearch index will change to something like this...: "_source": {"group": {...}, "event" : {....} } ....  as with multiple case class will have mutiple json to be written.

Comment: It is much easier to store and index nested objects that way in Elasticsearch than to try to fool the Scala compiler like you're doing.  Of course, the best solution would be to upgrade to Scala 2.11.

Comment: Thanks.. That's the simple approach, but is it the only solution, will have to change the ES index mapping also.             
   Scala Version can't be upgraded as of now.

Comment: I agree that changing the index is a pain--particularly because your eventual migration to Scala 2.11 will make it unnecessary and complicated. But given your constraints, I know of no better solution.